# pandas Dataframe from itertools.product output not able to be created

Tags: pandas, python-itertools

I want to create a Dataframe of all possible combinations:

```
Primary_function=['Office','Hotel','Hospital(General Medical & Surgical)','Other - Education']
City=['Miami','Houston','Phoenix','Atlanta','Las Vegas','San Francisco','Baltimore','Chicago','Boulder','Minneapolis']
Gross_Floor_Area=[50,100,200]
Years_Built=[1950,1985,2021]
Floors_above_grade=[2,6,15]
Heat=['Electricity - Grid Purchase','Natural Gas','District Steam']
WWR=[30,50,70]
Buildings=[Primary_function,City,Gross_Floor_Area,Years_Built,Floors_above_grade,Heat,WWR]
a=list((itertools.product(*Buildings)))
df=pd.DataFrame(a,columns=Buildings)
```

The error that I am getting is :

```
ValueError: Length of columns passed for MultiIndex columns is different
```

Comment: With your data structure, you might be better off storing everything in a dictionary. That would allow you to access both dictionary keys and values, and you avoid hardcoding a list for each case as suggested by the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a list with strings of the columns, i.e.

```
columns = ["Primary Function", "City", "Gross Floor Area", "Year Built", "Floors Above Grade", "Heat", "WWR"]
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns = columns)
```

As Mr. T suggests, if you do this frequently you will be better off using a `dict`.